# apache2 auth_basic dbd password mismatch

Tags: mysql, basic-authentication, apache2.4

I have set up an Apache2 server as a reverse proxy, which retrieves several services from virtual machines in my network. I am trying to set up basic authentication to limit some services to certain users, using a mysql database to store users and passwords.

I am certain that Apache2 is connecting to the database, and retrieving the appropriate usernames when I attempt to log in with http auth, as I have checked the mysql logs:

> 2017-12-12T16:14:20.338976Z      2542 Prepare   SELECT password FROM testTable WHERE username=?
>
> 2017-12-12T16:14:29.611520Z      2531 Execute   SELECT password FROM testTable WHERE username='testuser'

However, my authentication is always denied with a password mismatch.

> [Tue Dec 12 10:14:29.612762 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2729] [client 192.168.1.194:56047] AH01617: user testuser: authentication failure for "/protected": Password Mismatch, referer: http://192.168.1.217/landPage.php

```
<Location "/protected">
    AuthName "Authentication"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider dbd
    Require valid-user
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM testTable WHERE username=%s"
</Location>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Too late but probably would help somebody. I experienced the same issue with `sqlite3` on Ubuntu. First make sure that your password is encoded on Ubuntu according to this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html

I first SHA1 encoded my password with provided Python code from this Apache page https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html I did this at Ubuntu terminal and recieved this

```
>>> "{SHA}" + format(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1('1234567'.encode('utf-8')).digest()));
Result "{SHA}b'IOq+XWSw4hZ5boNPUtYf0LcDMvw='"
```

Then, I SHA1 encoded same string with `htpasswd` from Apache httpd pack. It gave almost same result

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin$ ./htpasswd -nbs testuser 1234567
testuser:{SHA}IOq+XWSw4hZ5boNPUtYf0LcDMvw=
```

Do you see the difference? The Python's result from terminal is prepended with single quote and b and appended with single quote. So remove it in Python or use `htpasswd`